# Unable to insert into SQL database

Tags: vb.net

I cannot insert the records in SQL DB though my code executes properly.

Here is my code for your review:

```
Dim connection2 As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server = VAIOO-PC\SERVER ; Database = cust_id ; Integrated Security= true "}

Dim dataadpt As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dataset As New DataSet
Dim message As String

If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
    message = "Male"
Else
    message = "Female"
End If
connection2.Open()
Dim thisDate As Date
thisDate = Today
```

Setup the SQL command with parameters.  Parameters protect from SQL injection exploits (and make your SQL easier to read/manage).

```
Dim command As SqlCommand = connection2.CreateCommand
command.CommandText = " insert into customer_id values (@cust_id, @fname, @lname, @contact_no, @address,@sex,@age)"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_id", Custid.Text)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", FName.Text)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", Lname.Text)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_no", Contactno.Text)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Address.Text)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", message)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_of_registration", thisDate)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age.Text)

connection2.Close()
```

Comment: 1. You forgot parameter `@date_of_registration` in your isnert command. 2. You have to execute the command with `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` before closing the connection

Comment: you should include the columns of your table then the parameters